# scanf function error message; floats and doubles

Tags: c, scanf

This small program should prompt the user for 
two numbers (guess and number) and compute 
the approximate square root for a number based 
on Newton-Raphson Iteration algorithm.

I have issues with scanf. 
Here is the warning message I get:

```
prog7-8.c: In function ‘approx_sqrt’:
prog7-8.c:19: warning: format ‘%f’ expects type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’
prog7-8.c:19: warning: format ‘%f’ expects type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’
prog7-8.c: In function ‘main’:
prog7-8.c:33: warning: format ‘%f’ expects type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’
prog7-8.c:33: warning: format ‘%f’ expects type ‘float *’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’
```

I don't see why I get this problem. 
Here is the program:

```
// Program to compute an approximate square root of a number
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

float abs_value (float x)
{
    if (x < 0)
        x = -x;
    return x;
}

float approx_sqrt (float x)
{
    const float epsilon = 0.0001;
    float guess;

    printf("Please, enter your guess:  \n");

    if (scanf ("%f", guess) == 1)
    {
        while (abs_value (pow(guess,2) - x) >= epsilon)
        guess = (x / guess + guess) / 2.0;
    }
    return guess;
}

int main (void)
{
    float number;

    printf("Please, enter your number:  \n");

    if(scanf ("%f", number) == 1)
        printf("The square root of %f is %f\n", number, approx_sqrt(number));

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you! 
PS I am at the initial stage, and don't yet have 
enough knowledge for sophisticated usage of scanf;
so, I am just trying to use only the basic features
of this function.

Comment: If you just search just a *little* on the use of [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (and related functions) you will see that you need to pass a *pointer* to the variable.

Comment: Even if you just look at the error message which says "expects type float*". Clearly "guess" doesn't have type "float *"?

Answer (score 1):

In `main`-

```
if(scanf ("%f", number) == 1)       // %f requires address of variable
               ^ & missing here  (add it)
```

in function `float approx_sqrt (float x)`-

```
if (scanf ("%f", guess) == 1)
                ^ & missing   (same here add &)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should pass reference or address of variable to scanf not just the variable

```
//if (scanf ("%f", guess) == 1) change
if (scanf ("%f", &guess) == 1)


//if(scanf ("%f", number) == 1) change
if(scanf ("%f", &number) == 1)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone! Indeed, I have forgotten &. I am new to programming, thus I guess these type of errors will pop up many times, until I get to grips with material. Thank you for explanations and help!

Answer (score 0):

The title of your question clearly shows that you didn't read the error message that the compiler gave you. It didn't say "expected type float", it said "expected type float*". Notice the * ? Compilers don't write random characters in an error message. Read your error messages properly!

Now think about it: What would scanf do with a float argument? Or a double argument? It would be totally useless for scanf. scanf needs a *pointer* to a variable where it can store the values that it scans.